# scrlayer-scrpage: Save/restore header/footers

Tags: header-footer, koma-script, scrlayer-scrpage

Is it possible to save/restore headers/footers in [`scrlayer-scrpage`](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/doc/scrguien.pdf)-style headings?

Comment: Please explain better what you mean ...